# Bijection function $f(x,y)= (x-y+1, 2x-2y+2)$

Tags: analysis, functions

[image]

The picture shows the solution of the injection.
how to solve bijection? 
I know the condition:
  for all $b$ in $\Bbb R^2$ exist $a\in \Bbb R^2$ such that  $b=f(a)$
I don't know what's next.

Comment: Take a look at the diagonal, that is consider $f(a,a)$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $f(0,0)=f(1,1)$.

It is not an injection and hence not a bijection.

Comment: where is the error in my solution? proposal?

Comment: you have to reach $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$ of which you didn't to conclude that it is an injection. In fact, we just reach $x_1=x_2-y_2+y_1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y)=(x-y+1)\cdot (1,2)$$therefore $f(x,y)$ is not a bijection. Actually it is a many-to-one correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is wrong since to prove an injection you start that $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$

And you must reach that $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$

Which means that $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$